# UnityCG.cginc source code / insights on methods

Tags: unity-game-engine, direct3d

So i'm trying to implement an own graphics engine with unity-like functionality in that project. I'm using hlsl in both, Unity and my own project. Now i'm transferring what i did in unity to my D3D11 project. Somehow i can't access any Unity build-in methods (still in unity) like .xyz on a half3, where i want to have insights on additional information in order to implement them properly.

Is there any way to access those methods or see how they are implemented? I tried downloading extensions for VS 2022 like "HLSL Tools for Visual Studio" or "ShaderLab VS" both didn't give me the usual option to inspect that class. Also the online documentation only tells you that there is given .xyz method, but doesn't provide any further information.

Comment: `.xyz` isn't a method, it's a [swizzle access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx9-graphics-reference-asm-ps-registers-modifiers-source-register-swizzling). It's also completely pointless on a 3 component vector as that vector is already equal to the `.xyz` temporary that would be generated.

Comment: I know, i was trying to understand the use on other formats tho, like a 4x4 matrix. So i guess in that case it returns a float3 containing the elements of _11 _12 and _13?